# is there a generalization of Muirhead theorem for negatives reals?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers, muirhead-inequality

Is there a generalization of Muirhead theorem for negatives reals? Because the original theorem is for only non-negative real numbers.

Comment: Please do not use all caps for a theorem name. A name drop lets us know which result you want.

Comment: When discussing theorems, you should post the actual theorem here. A lot of people who may be able may not be willing if you don't post it.

Comment: @Cameron Williams Just click the tag muirhead-inequality and read "about".

Answer (score 1):

For negative variables it's wrong.

Try
$$x^3+y^3\geq x^2y+xy^2.$$
$(3,0)\succ(2,1)$, but the inequality is wrong for $x+y<0$ and $x\neq y$.

Also, what we need to make with the following inequality?
$$x^{\sqrt2}+y^{\sqrt2}\geq2x^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}y^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}.$$

Sometimes it's true for all reals:
$$x^2+y^2\geq2xy,$$
but it not comforting.